# Maven Help, mvn is not recognized as an internal/external command

Tags: maven, environment-variables

My System variables are:

```
> set PATH
> %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
> Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1;M2=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
> Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin;MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

and my System Variables are:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1
```

EDIT:

Can Someone Just Please tell me how my System Variables are supposed to look like fully?
Thanks

Whats Wrong? When i run mvn --version, i get mvn is not recognized as an internal/external command.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is a bit strange and has some mistakes. Lets do the right way:

First go to your system variable PATH and change it to:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin
```

Create a new variable with the name `M2_HOME` and with the value `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1`

And another one with the name `MAVEN_OPTS` with the value `-Xms256m -Xmx512m`

This should solve your problem.

**UPDATE**

To fix the error that you said on the comment just create another variable with the name `JAVA_HOME` and with the value `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05`

Comment: Well, I did that. This is what i got: Error: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment.
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Comment: @user3643432 try the update that I put on my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your `PATH` should include directory where `mvn.bat` is located. According to your question, right now this directory is not included.

Try updating `PATH` like this:

```
set PATH [all what is already here];C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin
```

Also, to run Maven from Windows shell, you need `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. It should point to the place where JRE you want Maven to use is located. Most likely you'll want something like this, depending on exact path where your JRE is:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre8
```

You may need to relogin or even restart Windows to see effect.

Comment: Exactly. Sometimes watching a video is helpful

Comment: Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
JAVA_HOME = "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre8\bin"
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Comment: @user3643432 You need to remove "JAVA_HOME=" from the beginning of variable value, and use the correct path, my guess about your java location might be wrong.

Comment: @user3643432 Almost. JAVA_HOME shouldn't have /bin at the end. Yep, you need just to edit system variables. I'll update my answer with the values you need.

Comment: Im getting very confused, since i took advice from other people and my variables are a mess right now. Can you just tell me what my whole system and user variables should have?

Comment: @user3643432 see updated post. Your M2_HOME is ok, you need to add mvn.bat location to PATH and JAVA_HOME as I wrote.

Comment: im still getting problems with JAVA_HOME. Am i supposed to link it to my jdk or my jre>

Comment: @user3643432 You need to link your JRE.

Comment: Error: M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
M2_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1\mvn.ba
t"
Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of the Maven installation

Comment: @user3643432 Remove "mvn.bat" at the end of `M2_HOME`.