# Why am I getting a mvn is not recognized error?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, apache, maven

I am following a tutorial on installing Maven 3.2(shown below)
[image]

I downloaded and unzipped it into my desktop directory now it is stored here - "C:\Users\chris\Desktop\apache-maven-3.2.5"

I made sure to add the maven bin to my Path system variable. My Path system variable is now "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin; C:\Users\chris\Desktop\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin"

After doing this, I ran the mvn -version on my command prompt and got this output [image]

Does anyone know why I am getting and what the solution would be?

I looked at
[Maven Not Recognized 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755137/mvn-is-not-recognized-after-installation-maven-3) and [Maven Not Recognized 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701730/maven-help-mvn-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-external-command) and saw one of the issues was that the JAVA_HOME user variable isn't being set correctly but mine is set to my jdk directory - "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45"

Comment: if the cmd was already open before installing Maven you just need to close it and reopen again.

Comment: yeah closed it and reopened, same thing. thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space from your environmental variable path list which is being interpreted literally by Windows

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin; C:\Users\chris\Desktop\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin
                                      ^
```